# how to disable pagepilling.js behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagepiling.js

I am using this [jquery plugin](http://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/) .
I would like to disable this behavior on mobile devices. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [MatchMedia](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js)
to load the plugin only when the viewport reaches a certain size.

```
    if (matchMedia('only screen and (min-width: 480px)').matches) {
      // enable plugin
    }
```